# Get site address without protocol

Tags: php

How to get current site URL without http:// or https:// for both domain and subdomain ?

Input - > `http://www.example.com/` | Output -> `www.example.com` 
Input - > `http://site.example.com/` | Output -> `site.example.com` 
Input - > `example.com/`             | Output -> `www.example.com`

I tried to use `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` but that's not working exactly.

Comment: y i am getting dowvote for this  question ? :(

Comment: Because you did not searched google before you came here.

Comment: I did and  also mentioned above

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6768831/2765666) can help you to retrieve the URL. Once you have that, have a look at the [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function to process it:

```
$parsed = parse_url('http://www.example.com');
echo $parsed['host']; // www.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

For more check the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you explain further? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: it echo's `example.com/` for `example.com`

Comment: And how does that differ from what you want it to do? If you're expecting it do add a "www", like in your example above, that won't work with any function, unless you specificly programm it to do so.